# Unable to Update Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, upgrade, updates

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS and up until recently, I had no trouble updating it.  Now when I try, I receive the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
linux-headers-4.4.0-134-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-134 but it is not installed 
linux-image-virtual : Depends: linux-image-
```

This seems to have happened at the same time that the following message appeared when I log into my VPS:

```
New release '18.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

I have a few websites hosted on my VPS so I'd like to keep the OS updated with the latest security updates.  How do I fix this error message and update my OS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have unmet dependencies.

Possible cause of unmet dependencies could be corrupted package database and packages weren't installed properly. Try to trun the following commands to fix:

`sudo apt-get clean`

and

`sudo apt-get autoclean`

Resolve dependencies using:

`sudo apt-get -f install`

The -f option is "fix broken". `apt` will try to correct broken dependencies.

Then run:

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Finally run again:

`sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I did everything you listed but still getting an error

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-4.4.0-134-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-134 but it is not installed
 linux-headers-4.4.0-135-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-135 but it is not installed
 linux-image-virtual : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-135-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Comment: This package was deleted according to this source - https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/canonical_kernel_team/xenial/main/base/linux-headers-4.4.0-134-generic

Is this related to the problem I'm having?